# Why is a click event triggered only after mouse click and release?

Tags: web-development, javascript

Every click event on the web works on mouse click and release. Is there a way to do a action on a click event before mouse release??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because "mouse click" is defined as down/up in the same spot. On the other hand, down/move/up would not be a mouse click but a mouse drag. If you want to specifically listen for mouse button down, most event systems allow you to subscribe for mouse down event. In JavaScript, that would be the `onmousedown` event.

Comment: is it a good practice to use mousedown instead of click event?

Comment: personally, I find it poor usability to trigger stuff on mousedown.  I expect to be able to change my mind after pressing down on the button.  I do this by dragging away before releasing.

Comment: @MetaFight why would someone with the intention of clicking a button will move away after mouse down?

Comment: @PremAnand People change their minds, especially when acting hastily or the UI responding surprisingly. You may have misread the label or some other part of the UI. Or maybe even you wanted to click something, but then something else pops up under the mouse. Or you're using a bad mouse/touchpad and mistakenly click the wrong button. And so on, and so forth.

Comment: @PremAnand: I agree with others.  There's a reason why a generic-sounding "mouse-click" event was defined as down/up, in just about every UI framework. It's standard and that's what people expect. To give you an example of why, sometimes I would hold my hand over mouse while thinking about something and inadvertently click on a button or a link, it's almost instinct to simply move the mouse and release if I didn't actually want the action to go through.

Comment: As DXM mentioned, it's almost instinctual to drag the mouse and release to cancel an inadvertent click.  I'm sure many users do this without even realizing it.  In fact, I only realized I was doing it when the application I was using *didn't* allow it (the action was triggered on mouse-down alone).  It's jarring.  Hence my comment regarding usability.

Comment: Dont forget that there's browser- or OS- specific things which could happen on a click-and-hold (iOS uses it to bring up an option menu, for instance), so acting on mouse-down rather than mouse-click can produce undesired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you could trap onmousedown or onmouseup before the click event is fired.

> The onmousedown, onmouseup, and onclick events are all parts of a
>   mouse-click. First when a mouse-button is clicked, the onmousedown
>   event is triggered, then, when the mouse-button is released, the
>   onmouseup event is triggered, finally, when the mouse-click is
>   completed, the onclick event is triggered.

[Javascript Event Tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events#mouse-event-types)

Answer (score 1):

If you mouse-down on a button, move the mouse off the button surface and finally release the mouse, no mouse click event will be fired. This can save your day, if you have pressed the mouse on the delete-all-my-work-button inadvertently!